# Conflict with CSS will-change property

Tags: sticky, mmenu, will-change

The div with class mm-page that contains all the content has the CSS property will-change: transform;

This seems to cause conflict with other properties such as position:sticky;

Is it really necessary to maintain this style? Is there any alternative?

Thank you so much!

We are testing the plugin for our WordPress developments, our idea is to buy a multi-domain license and be able to integrate it into all projects. We hope to be able to maintain all the functionalities of the template we use in WP (GeneratePress) and the Elementor Pro page builder.

Comment: `will-change` should not have effects on your CSS, it is just used to hint to the browser which values should be optimised for animating etc... It's just an internal feature as far as I know.

Comment: In this link you can check it: https://en-desarrollo.eu/pruebas/ there are 2 elements with sticky that remain fixed, both the header and the heading "ASK US ANYTHING".

Comment: Please provide a more minimal example that reproduces the issue, as `will-change` should not have an effect on the stickiness of position. I am not going to debug this monster of a website (in size, its not a judgement on the result). Your sticky header indeed disappears when scrolling, but it has no `will-change` applied to it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more specific.

If you look for the div with the id "flag-for_ somethinghere" you will see that it has a position: fixed; and the header does not follow the scroll. If you look for the div added by the plugin (class="mm-page mm-slideout") and remove the will-change: transform; You will see that the fixed now works correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, no, I can't even find your target. Again, you'de do well in trying to recreate the issue in a simpeler context - I don't know and don't feel like digging through your entire CSS styles and setup to see what's going on here. Creating a minimal, viable example also helps you isolate the issue and perhaps even solve it already. Sorry I can't help more, but I also have clients that actually pay for my time...

Comment: From the beginning I have told you that our intention is to buy a multidomain license, but understand that first I want to confirm that the code works well with the template and constructor that we always use. I have reduced the DOM but I don't know how to make a simpler test that will help you check the case. The header has a fixed position and this position is not applied. Removing will-change in the div that adds mmenu does work.
Any support email that I can better contact? I insist, we are interested in using the plugin, but we want to see it working on this staging website.

Comment: I'm sadly enough not the person you should air your grievances too. I neither maintain the plugin nor provide support for it, and paying for that will not help me either. Sorry I can't help you further. It also seems no one else is able to help you out here - I have explicitly not answered or the like, so this question should still seems attractive to those with an interest in it. Good luck either way.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were the developer of the plugin. Thanks for your help too.